# when i was pass empty value in params all my datas are showed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def policy_details
  policy_details = Policy.where("policy_number LIKE ? or assured_name LIKE ? or application_number LIKE ? or proposer_name LIKE ?","%#{params[:policy_number].present?}%","%#{params[:assured_name]}%","%#{params[:application_number]}%",
                                  "%#{params[:proposer_name]}%")

  if policy_details.present?
    policy_details = policy_details.select(:assured_name, :policy_number, :application_number, :id, :issuance_date, :proposer_name, :policy_name, :base_premium)
  end
  output = {status: '10', data: policy_details}.to_json
  render json: output, status: :ok
end
```

Comment: i want pass some empty fields

Comment: you mean like `assured_name LIKE NULL` or `assured_name IS NULL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"%" matches everything, and you get all the records in the result.

```
so you can use ".present?". its working for if the value is that search was consider otherwise not.  

policy_details = policy_details.where('assured_name LIKE ?',"%#{params[:assured_name]}%") if  params[:assured_name].present?

    policy_details = policy_details.where('proposer_name LIKE ?',"%#{params[:proposer_name]}%") if  params[:proposer_name].present?

    policy_details = policy_details.where('application_number LIKE ?',"%#{params[:application_number]}%") if params[:application_number].present?

    policy_details = policy_details.where('client_id LIKE ?',"%#{params[:client_id]}%") if  params[:client_id].present?

    policy_details = policy_details.where('advisor_code LIKE ?',"%#{params[:advisor_code]}%") if  params[:advisor_code].present?
```

Answer (score 2):

If `params[:assured_name]` is nil or the empty string then

```
"%#{params[:assured_name]}%"
```

becomes

```
"%%"
```

Since `%` is a wildcard, doing a like on `'%%'` matches everything, and you get all the records in the result.

The database is behaving as expected.  You need to define what you want your query to be when there is no `assured_name`.